# layout/design_navigation_menu_item: <merge /> can be used only with a valid ViewGroup root and attachToRoot=true

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

yesterday I was using android studios and it was working normally, but when was it today. When I went to test my app on my cell phone this error appeared:

```
2021-07-30 12:46:53.204 10525-10525/com.brizaloka.brizasapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.brizaloka.brizasapp, PID: 10525
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.brizaloka.brizasapp/com.brizaloka.brizasapp.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17 in com.brizaloka.brizasapp:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #17 in com.brizaloka.brizasapp:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3338)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3487)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2071)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7561)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:995)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17 in com.brizaloka.brizasapp:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #17 in com.brizaloka.brizasapp:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17 in com.brizaloka.brizasapp:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:858)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1014)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:965)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1144)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1105)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:686)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:538)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:481)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:696)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:170)
        at com.brizaloka.brizasapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:35)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7893)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7880)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1306)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3313)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3487)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2071)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7561)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:995)
2021-07-30 12:46:53.205 10525-10525/com.brizaloka.brizasapp E/AndroidRuntime: Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17 in com.brizaloka.brizasapp:layout/design_navigation_menu_item: <merge /> can be used only with a valid ViewGroup root and attachToRoot=true
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: <merge /> can be used only with a valid ViewGroup root and attachToRoot=true
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:656)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:538)
        at com.google.android.material.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter.getMenuView(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:108)
        at com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:234)
        at com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:122)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:858)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1014)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:965)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1144)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1105)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:686)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:538)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:481)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:696)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:170)
        at com.brizaloka.brizasapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:35)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7893)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7880)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1306)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3313)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3487)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2071)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7561)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:995)
2021-07-30 12:46:53.213 10525-10525/com.brizaloka.brizasapp D/OOMEventManagerFK: checkEventAndDumpForJE: 0
2021-07-30 12:46:53.233 10525-10525/com.brizaloka.brizasapp I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 10525 SIG: 9
```

I've been trying for a while to find this problem, but every time I see something that seems to be giving this problem, this error is already familiar.

My MainActivity.java:

```
package com.brizaloka.brizasapp;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.brizaloka.brizasapp.ui.gadgets.requestPermission;
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private boolean playing = false;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow, R.id.nav_insert_api, R.id.nav_pesquisas,
                R.id.nav_ttp, R.id.nav_random_image, R.id.nav_gerador)
                .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.item_1:
                if(!playing) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Iniciando música...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    try {
                        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                        mediaPlayer.setDataSource("http://hyades.shoutca.st:8043/stream?partnertok=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6InR1bmVpbiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ0cnVzdGVkX3BhcnRuZXIiOnRydWUsImlhdCI6MTYyNjg4MDY3OCwiaXNzIjoidGlzcnYifQ.bLs22riwR5NrHEWAmSm2xRaX540yZDmRUzuXNyHjn4g");
                        mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
                        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                                mp.start();
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Música inicada com sucesso!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                playing = true;
                            }
                        });
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Música já iniciada", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;
            case R.id.item_2:
                if(playing) {
                    mediaPlayer.stop();
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Música pausada", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    playing = false;
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Música já está pausada", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;
            case R.id.item_3:
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://tunein.com/radio/Chillhop-Radio---Lofi-Hiphop-Beats---Chillsky-s288329/")));

        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#212121"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#212121"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:itemIconTint="#C3C3C3"
        app:itemTextColor="#C3C3C3"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"
        android:theme="@style/darkTheme"/>
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.brizaloka.brizasapp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/darkTheme"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="@string/ads_applicationID" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="Brizas App"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/darkTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name=".ui.gadgets.PushNotificationService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

build.gradle(module):

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

build.gradle (app)

````
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.brizaloka.brizasapp"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            res {
                srcDirs 'src/main/res', 'src/main/res/layout/gallery', 'src/main/res/layout/slideshow', 'src/main/res/drawable/res', 'src/main/res/drawable/item_icon_api', 'src/main/res/layout/pesquisa', 'src/main/res/layout/color_list', 'src/main/res/drawable/buttons', 'src/main/res/layout/ttp', 'src/main/res/layout/gerador', 'src/main/res/layout/hentai', 'src/main/res/layout/redes_sociais'
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.3'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.3'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.wear:wear:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.2.1')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:20.2.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.github.f0ris.sweetalert:library:1.5.6'
    implementation "com.github.zjupure:webpdecoder:2.0.4.12.0"
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.12.0'
    compileOnly 'com.google.android.wearable:wearable:2.5.0'

}
```
````

Comment: Clean and rebuild your project.

Comment: where do i find this on android studios?

Comment: In build section from top bar

Comment: I can't believe I spent 8 hours to solve a problem that was just pressing a button. Thank you friend it worked here!

Comment: You are welcome. I am just adding it as an answer. Kindly accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Clean and rebuild your project.